# ACF: load repeater field from a relationship field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I trying to load a repeater field from related posts with advanced custom field.

I have a post who has a relationship to load posts from another post_type. Then this post_type has a repeater_field. I tried to load these repeater_fields of my related posts. Its a object inside another object.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
  $posts = get_field('related_posts'); // this is a relation field
  if( $posts ): 
  foreach( $posts as $p ): 
?>

    <section class="slider">
        <?php 
            $quotes = get_field('slider_quotes'); // this is my repeater field

            if( have_rows($quotes) ):
                while ( have_rows($quotes) ) : the_row();
        ?>
      <div><h2><?php echo get_sub_field('quote'); ?></h2></div>

       <?php endwhile; else: 
                echo "Nothing yet"; 
        endif; ?>

    </section>
```

I already tried:

```
$frases = get_field('slider_quotes', $p->ID);
```

and

```
<?php echo get_sub_field('quotes', $p->ID); ?>
```

And I got nothing.

Thanks!

FULL CODE

https://gist.github.com/pailoro/1541717925d9cd9622ba

Answer (score 0):

If 'slider_quotes' is an repeater field, try to get with

```
<?php the_repeater_field('slider_quotes', $p->ID); ?>
```

refer the [link to get values of repeater field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_repeater_field/)

Comment: I tried, then I got this: ( ! ) Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /home/labbo/public_html/dugraf/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/core/local.php on line 671

Comment: what is on line #671. can you please post your full code?